# Problem with biholomorphic maps

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have the following problem:

> Let $U_1,U_2\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $\pi_1(U_i)=0$ and take $a_i\in
>  U_i.$ Let $f:U_1\to U_2$ be a biholomorphism with $f(a_1)=a_2$ and let
>   $g:U_1 \to U_2$ be holomorphic and injective with $g(a_1)=a_2.$ Show that
>   $|g'(a_1)|\leq |f'(a_1)|.$

I know that if $g$ is holomorphic and injective, $g'(z)\neq0$ for all $z\in U_1.$ I don't know how to use the fact that $U_i$ are simply connected. I've tried solving this using Cauchy's integral formula, I've tried doing some algebraic gymnastics with the theorem for differentiating the inverse of a holomorphic function and nothing. Also this is not true on $\mathbb{R}$ and for differentiable functions. Take $f(x)=x,$ $g(x)=x^3,$ $a_1=1$ and $a_2=1$ and take $U_1$ in such a way so that it contains the origin.

Comment: You need to assume that $U_i \neq \mathbb{C}$, the assertion doesn't follow for $U_1 = U_2 = \mathbb{C}$. Then you can assume that $U_1 = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ and $a_1 = 0$. [Why can you assume that, and how does that lead to the solution?]

Comment: First of all I've use the symbol $\subset,$ not $\subseteq.$ And by Riemann's theorem $U_i$ are biholomorphic to the unit disc and by a Mobius transfomation i can suppose that $a_1=0=a_2.$ Now I have to think how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Aa, then the problem is solved by Schwarz lemma!

Comment: It's quite common that $\subset$ is synonymous with $\subseteq$ and not with $\subsetneq$, conventions differ (and that's why it's in principle better to never use $\subset$ and always one of $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$, but nobody does it). Yes, Riemann mapping theorem plus the Schwarz lemma.